# How long does data stay in RAM of IoT devices?

Tags: security, memory, hardware, iot, computer-forensics

Hey I am researching on ways for forensic investigations of iot devices. I am still completely new to this field.

Let's assume we have a normal Amazon Echo Dot or a camera and I would want to investigate it so I can get audio data out of the RAM.

Does anybody know for how long data like this stays in the RAM of an IoT device, maybe like a standard time frame ? This does not have to be Amazon Echo Dot, the question would work with any iot device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's up to the discretion of the programmer who wrote the software and the tools used for implementing the software. Generally the most accurate answer would be slightly longer than the data is required to be retained for retrieval and processing purposes or until the device is switched off.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I also spoke with some people about that and it 
seems that its really impossible to generalize that time frame.